# How to make numbers in a html ordered list unselectable

Tags: html

If I have a ordered list such as

```
<ol>
<li>list item 1</li>
<li>list item 2</li>
</ol>
```

How can I make the numbering (the 1. and 2.) unselectable when highlighting the list items?

Comment: You mean the number before "list" or number after "item" ? Because in several browsers I tried the number *are* unselectable

Comment: I'm fairly sure he means the ones before as the ones after don't have a dot after them.

Comment: Please specify on which browser(s) the browser-generated numbers are selectable. On the five browsers I tested, even Select All (Ctrl+A) did not include them in the selection.

Comment: This happens in chromium/chrome, but not Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick (change selectors as necessary):

```
ol {
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
}

ol p {
    -webkit-user-select: all; /* Chrome/Safari */        
    -moz-user-select: all; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: all; /* IE10+ */
}
```

Comment: This can’t do the trick unless the markup is modified to contain `p` elements.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: That's why I said "modify selectors as necessary".

Comment: had to modify the php a bit to get the selectors working, but this answer works awesomely :). I still don't understand why it is selectable in some browsers, and not selectable in some, but with this applied, I guess its a moot point.

Thanks.